# Symfony Doctrine QB excess queries being generated

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have a series a similar queries to fetch a significant amount of information from the db.

They all have the basic set up as the one below, only with different tables.

The issue is that for each element in `$version_ids` it will generate `SELECT *` queries for 3 specific tables below.

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE version_id = $version_ids[n] // this only for explanation purposes

SELECT * FROM ct_insurance WHERE version_id = $version_ids[n]
SELECT * FROM costs WHERE version_id = $version_ids[n]
```

So, if $version_ids has 10 elements, it will generate 30 queries, 10 for each of the above tables.

The common point for those tables is that they have a one-to-one relationship with tables version, as for instance:

```
class Ct_insurance
{

/** 
* @ORM\Id 
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Version", inversedBy="ct_insurance") 
*/
private $version;
```

Also note that, even if a have the mentioned series of queries, those unwanted queries are generated only once. So, at least no 30 queries for each one of the queries in the series.

This is one instance of the query:

```
    public function getBrandPageData1($version_ids)
{
    $doctrineConfig = $this->getEntityManager()->getConfiguration();
    $doctrineConfig->addCustomStringFunction('field', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Field');

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select("v, field(v.id,:ids) as HIDDEN field")
        ->addSelect('b.brand AS brand')
        ->addSelect('b.imgLogoBig')
        ->addSelect('m.id AS model_id')
        ->addSelect('m.model AS model')
        ->addSelect('s.id AS segment_id')
        ->addSelect('s.segment AS segment')
        ->addSelect('v.id AS version_id')
        ->addSelect('v.version AS version')
        ->addSelect('v.places AS places')
        ->addSelect('i.imgPath AS img_path')
        ->addSelect('w.wrYear AS wr_year')
        ->from('AppBundle:Version', 'v')
        ->join('v.model', 'm')
        ->join('m.brandId', 'b')
        ->join('m.segmentId', 's')
        ->join('m.images', 'i')
        ->join('AppBundle:Warranty', 'w', 'WITH', 'w.brand = b.id')
        ->where('v.id IN (:ids)')
        ->orderBy('field')
        ->groupBy('v.id')
        ->setParameter('ids', $version_ids);
    try {
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

I tried to generate the same queries in DQL, but got an error on the GROUP BY clause.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found out what it was, or so it seems.

On the first `select`, the reference to `v` generates the entity object, which then apparently calls all mapped entities.

So this solved it:

```
$qb->select("field(v.id,:ids) as HIDDEN field")
```